# The secondary window is automatically hidden after after clicking the "OK" button of the Messagebox. Are you doing to hide it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Working in a secondary window with Tkinter, when I click on the "OK" button of the Messagebox message (Record insert correctly), this secondary window disappears and is hidden at the bottom of the taskbar. So immediately click "OK" in the Messagebox, I'll find myself automatically on the main window. I don't get errors

How can I not hide the secondary window in the taskbar and then stay inside the secondary when I click the "OK" button of the Messagebox? What should I write in the "Insert?"

Code Windows Main:

```
window=Tk()
window.title("main")
window.attributes('-zoomed', True)
```

Code Windows Secondary

```
from aaa import bbb

def form_secondary():

    root = tk.Toplevel()
    root.title("secondary")
    root.geometry("1920x1080+0+0")
    root.config(bg="white")
    root.state("normal")
```

Function that launches MessageBox

```
def insert():
    if aaaa() == "" or bbbb.get() =="" or cccc.get() == "" or ddddd.get() == "" or eeee.get() == "" or fffff.get() == "":
        messagebox.showerror("There is some empty field. Fill out all the fields")
        return

    db.insert(aaaa.get(), bbbb.get(), cccc.get(), ddddd.get(), eeee.get, fffff.get())
    messagebox.showinfo("Record insert correctly ")
    clearAll()
    dispalyAll()
```

Comment: Typo. You have `dispalyAll()`

Comment: Unsure if this will be causing your issue or not

Comment: @jezza_99  Thanks for reporting, unfortunately, however, the error is not this

Comment: Your description is a bit confusing: *"However, the secondary window is hidden only at the bottom of the taskbar, but is not closed"*. It means the secondary window is not closed. However your request: *"How can I do not to close the secondary window and remain inside it ..."*, the secondary window is not closed and so your request has already been fulfilled.

Comment: @acw1668  You're right. Sorry all. I "closed" I meant that she was hidden. I was wrong. I have correct title of the question and question. I hope for your suggestion

Comment: Try making `root` (child window) a transient window of `window` (root window): `root.transient(window)`.

Comment: @acw1668 I do not understand. Can you show me an example?

Comment: I have already given the code you need to add into `form_secondary()`.  A transient window will always on top of its parent and is it what you need?

Comment: @acw1668 Yes, but with your code I get the NameError: the name 'window' is not defined

Comment: Does `window` created inside a function? Since based on your posted code, `window` seems to be created in global scope and it should be accessible inside `form_secondary()`.  Or `window` and `root` are in different scripts?

Comment: @acw1668 In the main window, "windows" I have not created it in a function. I normally created it in the first staves. But they are two different scripts, two different py files

Comment: Then, you need to pass `window` to `form_secondary()` as an argument.

Comment: @acw1668 To what sense? Can you better explain yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a child window on top of its parent window by making the child window a *transient* window of parent window.

Since creation of `window` (in main script) and `root` (inside `form_secondary()` in another script) windows are in different scripts, you cannot refer `window` inside `form_secondary()` directly.  One of the way is to pass `window` to `form_secondary()` as an argument:

```py
def form_secondary(parent):
    root = tk.Toplevel(parent)
    root.title("secondary")
    root.geometry("1920x1080+0+0")
    root.config(bg="white")
    root.state("normal")
    # make this window a transient window
    root.transient(parent)
```

And then pass `window` as an argument when calling `form_secondary()` in main script:

```py
...
window=Tk()
window.title("main")
window.attributes('-zoomed', True)
...
# assume it is called inside a function
def some_func():
    ...
    form_secondary(window)
    ...
...
```

---

Update: if it is called via a menu item, then use `lambda`.

For example:

```py
editmenu.add_command(label='Database', command=lambda: name.form_secondary(window))
```

Comment: The secondary window calls it with a command, like this: editmenu.add_command (label = 'Database', command = name.form_secondary). I don't use functions to invoke the secondary window. The code you wrote will be useful for community readers so leave it, but can you add a solution for my command = name.form_secondary please?

Comment: You can use `lambda`: `command=lambda: name.form_secondary(window)`.

Comment: Right, I hadn't thought of that. But now I get the error editmenu.add_command (label = 'Database', command = lambda: name.form_secondary (window))
TypeError: result_form () takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: What is `result_form`? There is no such function in the line of code!  May be you update your code to provide a [mre].

Comment: Result Form would form_secondary. It is the name I have, I forgot to rename it for example for the demand. Pretend it is the form_secondary function

Comment: So the error is: editmenu.add_command (label = 'database', command = lambda: name.form_secondary (window)) typeeerror: form_secondary () takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: Did you modify the definition of `form_secondary()` as mentioned in the answer?  If yes, it should not have such issue.

Comment: I had changed it before when I wrote the error I received. I just wrote it wrong in the comment. So I'm still getting that error. I don't understand why

Comment: As I said, update your question with a [mre].

Comment: Everything ok, sorry. I hadn't seen that "parent" was also needed in root.transient (parent). Voted. Thanks for everything